# Setting request-user on IPP printer in CUPS

Tags: linux, networking, unix, printing, cups

I need to send a request to CUPS server with the specific request-user parameter - remote_user instead of local_user. How should I set the local CUPS server?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [CUPS release notes](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.6/relnotes.html), support for specifying a different username was added in CUPS 1.6b1:

- CUPS now supports a User directive in client.conf and the CUPS_USER environment variable for overriding the default username ([STR #3114](http://www.cups.org/str.php?L3114))

The Ubuntu bug report below (I can't make it a link due to ServerFault limits) is another place to look for information and workarounds for pre-CUPS 1.6b1, although the workarounds are not very practical.

bugs.launchpad.net/common-print-dialog-gtk/+bug/856776

Answer (score 1):

If you print using this command:

```
lp -d yourprintername -U yourusername /path/to/file
```

you'll find `requesting-user-name="yourusername"` in CUPS' `error_log` file (but your `cupsd.conf` needs to be edited to use `LogLevel debug` for that message to show up).

If you want to force a default option for ***all*** users, run this command as root:

```
lpoptions -d yourprintername -o requesting-user-name=someusername
```

[***Note:*** some versions of CUPS seem to mix up 'job-originating-user-name' and 'requesting-user-name'. So you know if my suggestion doesn't work for you...]

Comment: No. I want to use from desktop. Running this command from root does not affect the default on my system as well.

Comment: @Maciej: had forgotten to add the command.

Comment: I have 1.4.4. Do you know which does not?